# Returning data in table format

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am sending out an e-mail containing a data range via Google Apps Script, at the moment when the e-mail is sent out the data is returned in a format whereby the cell contents are simply separated by a comma between each one.

I'd like to have them sent in a table format or at least on different lines (there is only ever 1 column and a maximum of 5 rows depending on the range) - can someone help?

```
function sendemail () {


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Responses");
  var vCodes = ss.getSheetByName("Codes") 

  var vResults = targetSheet.getRange("D2").getValue();
  var emailAddresses = targetSheet.getRange("B2").getValue()

  var dataRangeDay = vCodes.getRange(1, 1, vResults, 1).getValues();
  var dataRangeWeek = vCodes.getRange(1, 2, vResults, 1).getValues();
  var dataRangeMonth = vCodes.getRange(1, 3, vResults, 1).getValues();
  var subject = "Here are your Wi-Fi Codes!";
  var vLength = targetSheet.getRange("C2").getValue();  
  var vCompareday = "24 hours";
  var vCompareweek = "7 days";
  var vComparemonth = "28 days";


  if (vLength.equals(vCompareday)) { 
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddresses, subject, dataRangeDay);
  }
  else

if (vLength.equals(vCompareweek)) { 
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddresses, subject, dataRangeWeek);
}
  else

if (vLength.equals(vComparemonth)) { 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddresses, subject, dataRangeMonth);
}

  targetSheet.deleteRows(2);
   vCodes.deleteRows(1,vResults); 
}
```

Comment: [This post might help]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476064/google-scripts-use-spreadsheet-data-to-populate-html-table-in-email)

Answer (score 0):

Send it with html format. The official api docs about advanced options explain it well with samples.